# Including layered navigation twice on some page

Tags: layered-navigation

We have a situation on a responsive website, in which we need to include the layered navigation twice into a page as on mobile it's hidden in one place and shown above the content.

Oviously rule of thumb is you can not call `catalog/layer_view` more than once on one page.

Comment: What theme are you using? For example, Magentos RWD theme has a column called `left_first` which, on mobile, moves above the content

Comment: why do you think `catalog/layer_view` block cannot use twice in one page ? I think if you are gonna use the same collection in both layered navigation,then there is no problem to include it in one page any number of times

Comment: there is no reason as its a singleton so the results are always going to be the same and held in the same object.

Also the package is bespoke and we are moving the layered nav into the content on mobile when the screen size is small so its tabbed under the category banner

Comment: yes. But in both cases, you are going to use the same collection right. I think you need to hide LN in content section all other views except mobile view. For mobile view only you need to show the that LN. So basically all of LN should hold same collection. So there is no issue

Comment: at the moment they are added via xml, but one of which is css hidden, are you talking about doing a php mobile check and adding them by creating the blocks rather than using the xml approach ?

Answer (score 1):

Officially there is no way of actually doing this very cleanly unless you have a module that rewrites the filter adaptors, as its caused by the inner joins. So on a time limit the easy way to do this

```
function moveBlock()
{
     // This will execute whenever the window is resized
      height =  jQuery(window).height(); // New height
      width= jQuery(window).width(); // New width
      if(width < 777)
      {
        jQuery('.move').insertBefore('.category-products');
      }else
      {
        jQuery('.move').insertBefore('.block-compare');
      }
}
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
        moveBlock();
    });
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    moveBlock();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include layered navigation twice. Based on the comments, I have a strong feeling that, both of those layered navigation holds same content (more specifically holds same filters). If that is the case, there is no problem to use `catalog/layer_view` block twice in your layout. But you may probably need to use two templates for both of the blocks in order to do necessary changes. That is, second layered navigation filter should define like this in your layout file

```
 <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="mobile.layer.view" template="custom/template.phtml" />
```

Now in the custom template file, `custom/template.phtml`, you need to copy the current content that comes inside the default layer view template file `app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/catalog/layer/view.phtml` plus required changes. Most probably this "change" is addition of a script that will hide the whole content of the template from views other than mobile views and shows the content of the custom template only when it is a mobile view.

**In short**  in this approach, we are using the second layer view block only in the case of mobile view. For rest view it will not shown in frontend. Adding a simple script inside the custom template will do the trick. This will let you avoid un-necessary rewrites

Comment: this incidently also fails the moment you have multiple blocks using  type="catalog/layer_view" this singleton, because of the queries it runs you get .... "You cannot define a correlation name " ... because the models already defined.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your theme folder => layout -> catalog.xml.

Find the label `<label>Catalog Category (Anchor)</label>`

You can see after the few lines the following code. Just remove or comment that. My problem is solved.

```
<block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnavig" before="-" template="catalog/navigation/sidenav.phtml"/>
```

Hope this would be help.
Thanks