# How to show layered navigation 2 times on category list with a different template file?

Tags: layered-navigation

I succeed to load 2 times layered navigation by using

```
<action method="insert"><blockName>catalog.leftnav</blockName></action>
```

The problem here is that I need to load another template file than catalog/layer/view.phtml

So I tried to do

```
<block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.layer.custom" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/custom.phtml"/>
```

Which works fine ... until I use the filters :

```
"You cannot define a correlation name 'custom_attribut' more than once"
```

Apparently we can't have 2 block type="catalog/layer_view"

So is there a solution to show layered navigation 2 times on category list with 2 different template file ?

**OR**

In the end I need to show only one attribute in the 2nd place, not the entire layered navigation.
So is it possible to load manualy the attribute in question depending of the current product list, as it is the case in the basic layered navigation ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

See this answer for where your error comes from:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14805672/3917602

So the edited answer has a clever solution, you just need to listen to what arrives and edit the parameters accordingly.

I solved this is a different way. For reasons of design ('design') we needed a full width block with options and the sidenav block of options. Both blocks were supposed to show different stuff just to completely confuse the user, as designers do.

So we used some horrid front end hacks instead, so clicks in the top block called clicks in the side block, with those side block clicks getting propagated through to change the page (ajax).

Had I thought at the time about the remove parameters from the url trick then I probably would have gone that way.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i already asked this question and after allot of investigation it turns out this is not actually possible without using two seperate templates that hold the same filters. But i found this seems to fail and error out aswell due to the singleton nature of the layered nav.  but you can use jquery to do this if you so wish.

[Including layered navigation twice on some page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/41557/including-layered-navigation-twice-on-some-page)