# How to enable or add layered navigation to search result page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, catalogsearch

I found some equal [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517853/magento2-add-layered-navigation-to-search-result-page), but no answers are available in Magento 2.

Any one can tell me how to enable or add layered navigation to search result page in Magento 2.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i guess you cant using magento functionality , as layered navigation requires a root category to assign to the layer collectionn and in search you dont have any category

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/58501/how-to-show-layered-navigation-2-times-on-category-list-with-a-different-templat

Answer (score 5):

It's tied to the attribute settings:

> If you need show layered navigation for some attribute then please
>   enable it in backend. Go to stores > attributes > product, find and
>   open needed attribute (for example price) and on tab "Storefront
>   Properties" configure "Use in Search Results Layered Navigation" - Yes

[Source](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1587)

Please check attached screenshot
[image]

Comment: Use in Search Results Layered Navigation is set to Yes. However its still not showing on the search result page.